How to fix Magento's built-in session management that conflict with how GTM handles sessions causing session regeneration issue
Anyone have this issue before, I notices even in a freshly installed magento 2.4.4p4 commerce edition this issue occur
Let me know if this is the correct page to post this issue or I should post this issue into a magento github community or Google Analytics community,
The issue can be replicated by installing fresh magento 2.4.4p4 commerce edition, added the GTM script as below onto a custom head script
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

Install Google Chrome GA4 Debugger Extension, navigate through magento system and analyse on the changes happening on the Session ID part
Refer below screenshot on how I track the changes in session ID
_ga_XXXXX refers to my GA session ID
notice the session ID here original is 1713951199
now notice that the session ID change to 1713950221
